# jquery val() inside custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

i have a function like this in my external javascript file (jQuery is already included in the main html file):

```
function userlogin(){
    $('#ologinbox').html('<div class="input"><div class="input-text"></div><div class="input-field"><img src="css/images/loading.gif" /></div></div>');
    var data = 'username=' + $('#loginusername').val() + '&password=' + $('#loginpassword').val();
    alert(data);
}
```

and my html is like this:

```
<div class="input">
<div class="input-text">UserName: <div>
<div class="input-field"><input name="loginusername" id="loginusername" /></div>
</div>
<div class="input">
<div class="input-text">Password: </div>
<div class="input-field"><input name="loginpassword" id="loginpassword" type="password" /></div>
</div>
<div class="input">
<div class="input-text"></div>
<div class="input-field"><input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="userlogin();return false;"/></div>
</div>
```

when I click on the button the returned values of `$('#loginusername').val()` and `$('#loginpassword').val()` which are displayed in the alert box are undefined.

I wonder why is that???

Comment: Woah, your "complete" code is "completely" different to the originally stated problem (which [doesn't exist](http://jsfiddle.net/W6E6J/), incidentally; please actually run your testcases before posting them here asserting that they don't work!). I'm sure you can narrow down the issue now by taking out the AJAX call (and if the problem goes away, then you have narrowed it down to that).

Comment: You now have two completely different questions in one. Please remove the original, broken, testcase as it bears no resemblance to your "complete" code.

Comment: @Tomalak the first code I gave is a sample of my real code and the only problem is the one I mentioned! the AJAX call works perfectly fine.

Comment: Then take it out of the question. It's not relevant and adds noise that is hard for us to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#ologinbox').html('<div class="input"><div class="input-text"></div><div class="input-field"><img src="css/images/loading.gif" /></div></div>');
var data = 'username=' + $('#loginusername').val() + '&password=' + $('#loginpassword').val();
```

Assuming that the login box you posted is part of a `div` with id `ologinbox`, you just replaced its contents and therefore lost the elements `#loginusername` and `#loginpassword`.

Replace the contents *after* retrieving the values:

```
var data = 'username=' + $('#loginusername').val() + '&password=' + $('#loginpassword').val();
$('#ologinbox').html('<div class="input"><div class="input-text"></div><div class="input-field"><img src="css/images/loading.gif" /></div></div>');
```

<sub>(Notice how your original code snippet *doesn't* include the surrounding `<div id="ologinbox">` that would have made this clear! Please in future put your testcase into jsfiddle.net to **verify** that it reproduces the problem, otherwise we're just guessing.)</sub>

Comment: yup.that was the problem.LOLs

Comment: +1 nice catch! I'm going to use this as a use case on why you should post all your code. @James Please update your question with the wrapper div for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Just use jQuery to handle the click event. Not sure why you simply aren't getting an empty string. To fix it, assign the attribute and consider using jQuery to handle the event.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#button").click(Foo);

        function Foo(){
           var myVar = $("#someInput").val();
           alert(myVar);
           return false;
        }

    });
</script>


<input id="someInput" value=""/>
<input  type="submit" />
```

Comment: thanks but I don't think that's the problem. the weird thing is my code actually worked fine until today!

Comment: @James well, everyone's posted code that replicates what you do without errors, so it might be something else that's giving problems

Comment: I don't see how this code snippet is functionally any different from the OP's.

Comment: @Tomalak, it's not. Just establishing that the code works. The problem is most likely somewhere else in his code. This was previous to the edit

Comment: @James could you add what part of the updated code does not work?

Comment: @JohnP: "Not sure why you simply aren't getting an empty string." I have no idea why you think that he should. The code should work, i.e. display a string containing the contents of the `input` box.

Comment: @Tomalak I meant if he doesn't type anything in. It shouldn't return `undefined` as we've already established the code works

Comment: @JohnP mentioned the problem at the end of the question.

Comment: @James That code looks ok and should work. Could you post your entire HTML page into jsbin or set it up in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in jsfiddle and there does this work correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/9gDas/. Have you bound another event on the submit buttton or can you post some more code? In jsfiddle i used jQuery 1.5.2, which version do you use?

EDIT:
As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/r4QG3/ the code which you provided works correctly. I can not test the ajax post. What is going wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/pvQGs/

```
<input id="someInput" />
<input id="submitter" type="submit" />

$("#submitter").click(function() {
    var myVar = $('#someInput').val();
    alert(myVar);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is precisely equivalent.

Comment: yeah I know that works but I just want to know why mine won't!